# How to play a loud alert sound (beep) in Android

Tags: android, audio

In my app I need to play a loud sound as an emergency alarm. I'm trying this but I would like to produce something louder if possible (the loudest I could get).

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

ToneGenerator tone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, 100); // 100 is max volume
tone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 500); // 500ms
```

Do you know how to produce the loudest sound?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/13041314/1741542

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the device has a hardware button that triggers a very loud alarm (sounds like a siren, with changing pitch). I wanted to play that kind of loud sound. I'll try to figure out whether I can play that same sound or play something similar using any audio apis.

Comment: @Stephan : It's playing from loudspeaker

Comment: I'll investigate this way of generating arbitrary sounds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3731075/1121497

Comment: @FerranMaylinch did you manage to get it?